# Include part of an external webpage

Tags: html, load

I'm trying to make an html file that will grab the latest xkcd comic and display it, by requesting the web page and removing the  marked id="comic". I've tried using the following code:

```
<div id="xkcdArea"></div>
<script>
$("#xkcdArea").load("http://www.xkcd.com #comic");
</script>
```

But nothing displays. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Do I have to .get() the webpage first, and then load from that?

Answer (score 0):

there is space http://www.xkcd.com#comic..remove it

Comment: Tried this, same result (nothing displayed in that area).

According to http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments , there should be a space...

Comment: I got.. you need to use server side technology any how. `php DOMDocument` is one of solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have your website instruct a browser to fetch content from someone else's website and to make that data available to your JavaScript.

Browsers [do not allow this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for security reasons. (What if I was logged into my bank's website?)

See [ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for approaches to work around this. Given that you are unlikely to have the co-operation of XKCD in displaying their content on your website, you will probably have to resort to [using a proxy](/a/3076439/19068) to fetch the data.

You should consult a copyright lawyer before proceeding.

Comment: If I were to use [xkcd's RSS feed](http://xkcd.com/rss.xml) instead, how would I go about that?

Comment: Additionally, would I be able to process an iframe to pull out the desired item?

Comment: The restrictions on fetching RSS are exactly the same as the restrictions on fetching HTML. The APIs to read data from and communicate across domains using iframes are completely different from XHR, but (again) without the co-operation of the other site, you are prevented from reading data (for exactly the same reasons).